# TestNG with Java

Tags: testng

On using TestNG with Java, i get the following error:
'Type mismatch: cannot convert test to Annotation'

Note: Using eclipse IDE.
The build path has the TestNG jar included
Also TestNG plugin for eclipse IDE has been installed.

Could you please tell me why i get the above error?

Thanks

Code:

```
import org.testng.annotations.*;
public class ChangeResolutionOnMainWatch {

    @BeforeTest

    public void startTest() throws Exception {
        watch.startSelenium();
        stream_delay=Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("stream_delay").trim());
    }

    @Test 

    public void launchFalcon()throws Exception{

        watch.deleteAllCookie();
        watch.launchFalcon();
    }
}
```

In the above piece of code the '@Test' notation gives the error

Comment: What code gives you this error?

Comment: Could you post some code where you are getting this error ? Also did you try with a test app on the set up ?

Comment: @niharika_neo: code posted above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though import org.testng.annotations.*;
imports everything, it did not work.
But when I imported only the required classes it worked fine.

**BEFORE:**

```
import org.testng.annotations.*;
```

which did not work

**AFTER:**

```
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;   
import org.testng.annotations.Test;   
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
```

which worked

Comment: this is what i have suggested in post. You should acknowledge that.

Comment: @rai.skumar But when you import org.testng.annotations.*;   what is missing ?

Comment: that's a strange thing...but thing to notice here is "type mismatch error" --this gives a hint that there is some problem with import.

Answer (score 1):

Check if your imports are proper like :

```
  import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
  import org.testng.annotations.Test;
```

Usually you get **can't be resolved to a type** error if import is missing.